# React Native: Is it possible to prompt a splash screen every time the user goes out of focus?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I was wondering if it was possible to show the user the splash screen every time he opens the application after going out of focus (navigating to other open applications, and then coming back to mine).

So if a user opens the application, and then navigates to another one without closing mine, he must go through the splash screen again. I could not find any library or method that does this.

Comment: You won't find any library for this as this is not a good approach & would make your users feel like the app keeps loading on every resume. SplashScreen should only be used on a Cold Start. However not exactly React Native but if you still want to implement then you should use an `Observer` on `ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle` to handle app-wide Pause, Resume states & show splash accordingly.

Comment: I thought it might be bad practice, but the reason I needed it, is because I want to constantly check if the user has allowed location access permission, and to make sure the location setting is turned on because it's needed for various features within the app. Looks like I will have to find another approach then. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `AppState` from `react-native`.

```
import { AppState } from "react-native";

const appStateChangeListener = (val) => {
  if (val == "active") {
    //val will be "active" only when app is in foreground
    // use navigation to navigate to Splashscreen
  }
};
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = AppState.addEventListener(
    "change",
    appStateChangeListener
  );

  return () => {
    AppState.removeEventListener("change", appStateChangeListener);
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

what @sandarshnaroju is actually perfect, my code is as follows:

```
const [outOfApp, setOutOfApp] = useState(true);
const appStateChangeListener = (val) => {
  if (val == "active") {
    //val will be "active" only when app is in foreground
    // use navigation to navigate to Splashscreen
    console.log("Out");
    setOutOfApp(false);
  } else {
    console.log("in");
    setOutOfApp(true);
  }
};
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = AppState.addEventListener(
    "change",
    appStateChangeListener
  );

  return () => {
    AppState.removeEventListener("change", appStateChangeListener);
  };
}, []);
if (outOfApp) {
  return <SplashScreen />;
} else
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
      <AppNav />
    </Provider>
  );
```

where you can put in your splashscreen component whatever you like!